# PowerShell - Convert Server LastBootUpTime into DateTime format

Tags: powershell, datetime

Have some sections to the code I'm trying so I'll split them up.

```
$SERVER_NM = get-content env:computername
$LAST_UP_TIME = Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $SERVER_NM | select @{LABEL='LastBootUpTime';EXPRESSION={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}}
$dtformat = "\[MM.dd.yyyy HH:mm:ss tt\]"

$CURRENT_TIME = Get-Date -f $dtformat

echo $CURRENT_TIME.GetType():
echo $LAST_UP_TIME.GetType();

echo $CURRENT_TIME
$CURRENT_TIME = [datetime]::ParseExact($CURRENT_TIME,$dtformat,$Null).AddSeconds(-300).ToString($dtformat)
echo $CURRENT_TIME
echo $LAST_UP_TIME
```

To start with, I'm getting the last time my server rebooted with line 2.
I'm then getting the current time on line 5 with the format specified on line 3.
I'll be printing out the type of each of those calls.

I'm then subtracting 5 min (300 seconds) from the current time and printing out CURRENT_TIME again.

Here's the output of those echo calls.

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                     
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                     
True     True     String                                   System.Object                                                                                                
:
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object 

[07.14.2020 17:29:23 PM]
[07.14.2020 17:24:23 PM]

LastBootUpTime : 7/13/2020 2:59:49 PM
```

As you can see, there are two different types and the two CURRENT_TIME stamps are 5 minutes apart.
Additionally, the $LAST_UP_TIME has a different format altogether.

What I want to do - is be able to convert the LAST_UP_TIME to the same format as CURRENT_TIME ($dtformat).
Here is what I'm trying...

```
$LAST_UP_TIME = [datetime]::ParseExact($UPTIME, $dtformat, $Null).ToString($dtformat)
```

But I get an error. What can I do differently?
$LAST_UP_TIME.ToString() so that the type matches?

If you copy the PowerShell code you can run it in your own ISE, your computer's last reboot time will be substituted.

Comment: I tried placing a $LAST_UP_TIME = $LAST_UP_TIME.ToString(); in my code.
and then running the ParseExact command in the final codeBlock in the OP, but
Powershell threw this error: 
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:18 char:1
+ $UPTIME = [datetime]::ParseExact($LAST_UP_TIME, $dtformat, $Null).ToS ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException

Comment: use the CIM cmdlets if you can. they return `[datetime]` objects instead of `[filetime]` objects.

Comment: also, WHY are you converting your datetime objects to _strings_? leave them as DT objects so that you can use the DT methods on them - and can use them in date math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...]But I get an error

I didn't test this, but you are likely getting an error similar to "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

`$LAST_UP_TIME` is an object (proven by your `GetType()` output), so you can't do string/date manipulation.

The easiest way around your problem is to:

1. Use `$LAST_UP_TIME.LastBootUpTime` to reference the `LastBootUpTime` object so you can handle it as a date format
2. Pass this to `Get-Date` so you can format it how you want

See below line comments for the 2 lines you need to add to your code snippet.

```
$SERVER_NM = get-content env:computername
$LAST_UP_TIME = Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $SERVER_NM | Select-Object @{LABEL='LastBootUpTime';EXPRESSION={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}}
$dtformat = "\[MM.dd.yyyy HH:mm:ss tt\]"

$CURRENT_TIME = Get-Date -f $dtformat

# New variable to store formatted date
$LAST_UP_TIME_FORMATTED = Get-Date $LAST_UP_TIME.LastBootUpTime -f $dtformat
Write-Output $CURRENT_TIME.GetType():
Write-Output $LAST_UP_TIME.GetType();

Write-Output $CURRENT_TIME
$CURRENT_TIME = [datetime]::ParseExact($CURRENT_TIME,$dtformat,$Null).AddSeconds(-300).ToString($dtformat)
Write-Output $CURRENT_TIME

# Write-Output LAST_UP_TIME in desired format
Write-Output $LAST_UP_TIME_FORMATTED
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I needed, I did find the .LastBootUpTime but didn't know I could pass it to Get-Date!